# convert time format 00:44:50 To ('00:44:50.240000')

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
            string val;
            val = Request.Form["timerData"].ToString();            
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Convert.ToInt32(val.ToString()));
            lbTime.Text = ts.ToString();
```

- Here lbTime.Text returns me the time value in 00:44:50 format.
- In my Sql Database I have used Time(7) datatype for time and its
  Default value is ('00:00:00.0000000')
- I want to convert this format 00:44:50 To ('00:44:50.240000') and enter it in database using update statement.

*Time Above is for Example Purpose*

Please help me with the same.

Comment: where do those fractions of seconds come from? (the 24...)

Comment: That is for example purpose. I want data to be entered with milliseconds also.

Comment: So ... you need to take an existing timestamp... recorded in the past... and magically fudge extra precision onto it.  Just make up numbers, nobody will ever know

Answer (score 1):

If your update statement is *parameterized* or you use a stored procedure, [passing a `TimeSpan` to a `time(7)` column should work perfectly fine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx). Something like this:

```
public static void UpdateTimestamp( int id , TimeSpan ts )
{
  using ( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection( "some-connect-string" ) )
  using ( SqlCommand    command    = connection.CreateCommand() )
  {
    command.CommandText = "update foo set duration = @duration where id = @id" ;

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@id"       , id ) ;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@duration" , ts ) ;

    connection.Open() ;
    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery() ;
    connection.Close() ;

    if ( rowsAffected == 0 ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "That didn't work B^(" ) ;
    if ( rowsAffected >  0 ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "That shouldn't have happend B^(" ) ;

  }

  return ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 8, 29, 19, 27, 15, 18);
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("hh:mm:ss.f", ci));
// Displays 07:27:15.0
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("hh:mm:ss.F", ci));
// Displays 07:27:15
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ff", ci));
// Displays 07:27:15.01
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("hh:mm:ss.FF", ci));
// Displays 07:27:15.01
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff", ci));
// Displays 07:27:15.018
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("hh:mm:ss.FFF", ci));
// Displays 07:27:15.018
```

You can even use more 'FFFFF's in order to represents up to **seven** most significant digits of the seconds fraction.

Taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Does it helps?

Comment: This is a link answer.  Link answers are generally discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

In your last expression you say

```
ts.ToString()
```

This overload only displays fractional seconds if not all digits are zero. You may want to use a custom format string, as in

```
ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.fffffff")
```

instead. This ought to work in .NET 4.5 and 4.0. See [MSDN: Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I used the same code only mistake was i was converting value to int before passing it to timespan

```
string val;
            val = Request.Form["timerData"].ToString();            
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(val.ToString()));
            lbTime.Text = ts.ToString();
```

**Solved**